# integer literal is too large error

Tags: substrate-node-template

I was following the substate documentation of authorize specific nodes tutorial

referance:-https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/

In the add genesis storage for authorized nodes I want to add different nodes other than the predefined nodes(ALICE AND BOB) as authorized nodes so using the subkey I generated two keys for two nodes ec1 and ec2 and tried to add their peerid and account id as argument as in the figure attached

[image: added custom peerid and account id inplace of BOB and ALICE accounts]

but it is giving the following error:

[image: Error in the account id]

Please kindly help ....how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter you are giving is not in right format you can do it in two was:

1. Change the endowed accounts and use it that account `endowed_accounts[0].clone()` like this on the place of 0 you can right the index of your on which you have added the endowed index.
2. The other way is to add the account that you want add in the `customSpec.json` before make the `customSpecRaw.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f4a2e84ee5974b219f2a03cd195105060c41e3cd/frame/node-authorization/src/lib.rs#L113
>
> https://docs.rs/array-bytes/6.1.0/array_bytes/fn.hex2bytes_unchecked.html

The correct type is `Vec<(PeerId, T::AccountId)>`.

But here is what you passed to: `Vec<PeerId, integer)>`.

You should do:

```rs
OpaquePeerId(
  ss58::decode(...).into_vec().unwrap(),
  array_bytes::hex2bytes_unchecked("your account id in hex format here, e.g. 0x..."),
)
```